# Extract a number after a number pattern in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL server. I have some number like `130-0029`. I need to get the integer after the `-` delimiter out of it.  So in this example I need to return `29`. These are the following scenarios I have with this,

- The pattern may differ like `130-00000029` or `130-0029`.
- If there are all 0's then print `0`, else get actual number like `29`.

Please advise/suggest me on this.

Comment: Break it up into multiple number-type fields and print them that way?

Comment: 130-0029 is not a valid number. I assume you mean the portion after the -?? Then as @AdamV suggests cast that portion to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @num varchar(50) = '130-0029'
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@num, CHARINDEX('-', @num) + 1, LEN(@num)) AS INT)
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/385963/495938/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = '130-0029'
select cast(substring(@s, patindex('%[-]%', @s) + 1, len(@s)) as int)
```

You may need to cast to some numeric if the number overflows ineteger type.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if the `-` is missing.  But if what follows is not a number it will give an error.

```
declare @string as varchar(100)
set @string = '130-0029'

select convert(int,Right(@string, LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('-', @string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not so different than other answers, but this works using STUFF too:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10) = '130-0029';

SELECT CONVERT(INT, STUFF(@String, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @String), ''));
```

See this running in [Query Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/385954).